# MySQL шаблон WHERE id = *

Tags: mysql

есть шаблон запроса

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM answers WHERE user_id=$id"
```

в него подставляю переменную $id - ид пользователя. Как заставить его работать, когда мне нужны все строки т.е. типа `WHERE user_id=*` , какую `$id` передать?

Comment: Если Вы замените равенство на оператор LIKE, то можно передавать либо требуемый ИД пользователя, либо шаблонный знак процента. При этом строку сравнения необходимо обрамить одинарными кавычками: `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM answers WHERE user_id='$id'"`. Соответственно `$id=123` будет искать строго заданный ИД, а `$id="%"` вернёт все ИДы.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM answers WHERE (user_id=$id or ($id is null))`

или

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM answers WHERE user_id=coalesce($id,user_id)`

тогда

`$id = NULL;`

PS: $id должен быть соответствующим образом подготовлен, иначе это SQL-иньекция.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше не усложнять запрос, а добавлять условие тогда, когда оно действительно необходимо. Например так

```
   "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM answers". ($id ? " WHERE user_id=$id" : "")
```

Если предполагается несколько необязательных условий бывает удобно делать так

```
   $sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM answers WHERE 1=1";
   if($id)     { $sql.=" AND user_id=$id"; }
   if($field1) { $sql.=" AND filed1=$field1"; }
```

Для избежания возможных sql-инъекций обязательно проверяйте все переменные на корректность (например применяйте `$id=int($id)`). А еще лучше не подставлять переменные непосредственно в текст запроса, а поставить вместо них плейсхолдеры (обычно `?`) и использовать [привязку переменных](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) к запросу.

Answer (score 0):

Если ваша задача - получить все строки у которых указан какой-либо id, то вам необходимо `=$id` заменить на `NOT NULL`, так как если поле не заполнено - то оно считается пустым, т.е. NULL. Ну и для этого есть своя проверка.

Answer (score 0):

Стандартный подход в таких случаях - использовать конструкцию

```
... where @id is null or id = @id
```

Ну и ещё у тебя в коде sql injection.